# Как переправить человека в чат при нажатии на кнопку в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telebot, telegram

есть бот написанный на python с помощью библиотеки pytelegrambotapi, как организовать переход из чата бота в чат личных сообщений пользователя (например @123), при нажатии на reply кнопку?

Comment: Под "чатом личных сообщений пользователя" вы имеете в виду чат Избранное?

Comment: Нет, просто чат. Мне нужно чтобы перекидывало на моего человека для тех поддержки.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно использовать параметр `url` и просто перенаправить пользователя по ссылке нужного человека
т.е в `url` надо указать ссылку на телеграм

Пример с инлайн кнопкой: (с `reply` кнопкой нельзя)

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
url_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перейти в чат", url="https://example.com")
keyboard.add(url_button)
bot.send_message (message.chat.is , "любой текст", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Comment: Нет, мне нужно на клавиатурную кнопку, а не на инлайн.

Comment: Внёс изменения.

Comment: Unexpected keyword argument “url”

Comment: Попробуйте с больших букв, тюе URL

Comment: У keyboardbutton могут быть только аргументы (request_(contact, location, poll, user, chat); web_app)

Comment: С ``reply`` кнопкой нельзя, только инлайн